# Set country as parameter in Checkout tag

Tags: expresso-store

To make the checkout tag more user friendly, I would like to set a country parameter in the Checkout tag. Making it display the correct shipping cost using the ip-to-nation functionality.

Installation details:

- Expresso Store 2.4.1
- MC Country 1.0.1
- Expression Engine 2.9.2 (with ip2nation module enabled)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with MC Country and have not used IP2Nation in a long time but you would need to use a conditional for the `shipping_country` field against the data returned from IP2Nation.

```
<select name="shipping_country">
 <option value="US" {if ip2nation_tag_here == "US"}selected="selected"{/if}>United States</option>
 <option value="CA" {if ip2nation_tag_here == "CA"}selected="selected"{/if}>Canada</option>
</select>
```

and so on for each of the countries that you might ship to.

The other thing is that either you will need to update the cart with JS or have the user update the cart before you will get rates calculated.

Comment: That's what I came up with. Another solution is to embed the cart from an other template, and setting the country as embed parameter. Not ideal and quite slow.